# Odd and even functions, sum, difference and product

Tags: functions

If $f$ and $g$ are both odd, show that:

a) $f+g$ is odd

b) $f-g$ is odd

c) $fg$ is even

Comment: How do you plan to handle that ?

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

What does it mean for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be *odd*?

It means $f(-x) = -f(x)$ and $g(-x) = -g(x)$ for every real number/input $x$.

Now, to show, for example, $f + g$ is odd, you need to show for every real number $x$, $(f + g)(-x) = -(f+ g)(x)$.

I'll help you with this one, and the others are left to you:

$(f + g)(-x) = f(-x) + g(-x)$ by the definition of $f + g$, right?  But $f$ is odd, and so is $g$, so the above equals $(-f(x)) + (-g(x))$.  Then we can factor out the $-$ sign to get that it equals $-(f(x) + g(x))$.

So, we got $(f + g)(-x) = -((f+g)(x))$, which means $f + g$ is odd.

Comment: @ChrisSmith I should have mentioned a function is *even* if $h(-x) = h(x)$ for every real number/input $x$.  So for part $c$, you need to show if $f$ and $g$ are both **odd**, then $fg$ is **even**, i.e., $(fg)(-x) = (fg)(x)$ for every real number $x$ (and this end result is different than what you need to show for parts a and b).

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary constants $a,b$

$af(-x)+bg(-x)=-\{af(x)+bg(x)\}$

$f(-x)\cdot g(-x)=-f(x)\{-g(x)\}$